# Postgresql, how get one row for each distinct relation_id value in one pass over table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

For example, we have table:

| id | value | relation_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value1 | 1 |
| 2 | value2 | 2 |
| 3 | value3 | 1 |
| 4 | value4 | 1 |
| 5 | value5 | 3 |

And I want get rows with ids 1, 2, 5, for example (because they have distinct relation_id values). It is easy, but not if you have several billions rows. It is pretty slow even on SSD drive.
I have each possible value for relation_id and I tried such query:

```
(select value, relation_id from table where relation_id=2 limit 1)
union
(select value, relation_id from table where relation_id=3 limit 1)
-- so on
```

But turns out that for each subquery postgresql looking in the table from begining despite that it is one query. Is there a way to write query in such manner, that postgresql make single pass over table and collect required data along the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach 1**: Use PostgreSQL `DISTINCT ON` operator. It will match only distinct values of the field(s) inside the parentheses, given an `ORDER BY` clause, to prevent duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(relation_id) id_, value_, relation_id
FROM tab
ORDER BY relation_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2JvJ8PyQJXvdhkaiSVodaZ/0).

---

**Approach 2**: Use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function to generate a ranking over your records partitioned per "*relation_id*", then select the first record for each relation (rownum = 1)

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY relation_id ORDER BY id_) AS rn 
    FROM tab
)
SELECT id_, value_, relation_id 
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2JvJ8PyQJXvdhkaiSVodaZ/1).

---

**Approach 3**: Use `ROW_NUMBER` inside the filtering construct `FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES`, which will act as Approach 2 but avoids you the subquery (gets tied rows, tied on rownum=1).

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY relation_id ORDER BY id_) = 1 DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2JvJ8PyQJXvdhkaiSVodaZ/2).

Comment: It is work on smaller versions of table, but somehow first query consuming more than 49GB of temporary space when executing, and it is all space that left on device :( 
Despite it is should be something just about 900 rows (this is how many distinct relation_id I have)
Why postgresql consume more than 50GB of space to find 900 rows?

Comment: It's not much about finding 900 rows, it's about aggregating to 900 rows from lots of many more rows. Anyways, the answers that use window functions should be the smoothest ones (first one uses aggregation).